# Error with "touchesBegan"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitouch, cgpoint

My code:

```
var location = CGPoint(x:0,y:0) 
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { 
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as? UITouch 
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view) 
    Button.center = location 
}
```

Gives an error on this line:

```
let touch = touches.anyObject() as? UITouch
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this : - 

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch in touches {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
                           if touch.tapCount == 2{
                                //Do Something here
                            }
                                             }
                          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch
{
}
```